# Can a solid object inside the black hole event horizon avoid the singularity?

Tags: black-holes, causality, singularities, event-horizon, matter

I will ask this as a simple lay man. Let's consider an astronomical black hole that was creating by in falling matter on a neutron star. As neutron star get heavier it gets smaller and a Schwarzschild  radius corresponding to that mass gets bigger and bigger. At some point, when mass is big enough the neutron star gets smaller than its corresponding Schwarzschild radius then the neutron star disappears behind event horizon.

The Wikipedia article on [black holes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_hole) says that it can be shown that all mass inside black hole gets concentrated in central singularity. But why? Isn't it possible for a neutron star to live inside black hole, just invisible to us. Yes you might say that neutrons get collapsed, but they can collapse in some other form of matter and there is now a quark ball or some other exotic stuff that makes a solid sphere of some size.

Another source says that all geodesics lead to central singularity. I will make an analogy here. On earth some geodesics point to the center of the earth, If I let go of a stone it will fall towards center of the earth until it hits the ground. So, can matter falling into black hole eventually hit the surface of this neutron/quark/exotic stuff ball inside black hole. What prevent this? Let's assume that there exist some form of matter that resists the pressure of gravity be it neutrons, quarks or something more exotic which we don't know of yet.

EDIT: Although this question was marked as duplicate it is by no means a duplicate of the indicated question. The flagging just demonstrates lack of understanding of both questions.

Comment: If you start at the north pole and walk in any direction along the surface and then move on a geodesic on the surface, you end up the south pole, every single geodesic is sent there. Postulating gravity resistant objects is denying the whole point of GR, which is to have gravity be caused by curvature, thus explaining everything reacting the same way. If some things are immune then you can't use curvature to model gravity. And there aren't solid objects. That said, sure you could hit the surface of the collapsing neutron star, but that surface itself will still collpase into the singularity.